# SwiftUI Buttons in HStack not correct width

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am having some issues with creating a view.

[image]

**Contentview**

```
VStack{
    Capsule()
        .fill(Color.white)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 5)
        .padding(.top)
        .padding(.bottom,5)
    
    Text("Hello world")
        .font(.title)
    //Time
    ScrollView(.horizontal){
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("First")
            }).buttonStyle(TimeframeButtonStyle())
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Second")
            }).buttonStyle(TimeframeButtonStyle())
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Thirdiary")
            }).buttonStyle(TimeframeButtonStyle())
    
        }.frame(height: 100)
        
    }
    //Type
    HStack{
        
    }
}
```

**ButtonStyle**

```
struct TimeframeButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .font(.title)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25.0).stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1))
            
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            
    }
}
```

As you can see, the buttons are inside a scrollview, which then contains an HStack.
The problems is that the buttons try to fit on the same screen.

What I am searching for is how to make the buttons its naturally size?

FixedSize creates this, which makes the label too close to the borders[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to make the buttons its naturally size?

You can try `fixedSize()`:

```
Button(action: {
    
}, label: {
    Text("First")
})
.buttonStyle(TimeframeButtonStyle())
.fixedSize()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pawello. I have tried this and it causes some issues with the label. Have updated my question to include the results of fixedSize

Comment: @Pr0tonion You can apply `.padding()` to the `Text`.